# resizing wxListView with sizer

Tags: c++, listview, wxwidgets, sizer

I'm struggling to resize my wxListView when resizing my wxFrame. I managed to resize ListView's parent panel and wxButton in the same panel also moves with resizing the window as intended.

```
BluetoothConnectFrame::BluetoothConnectFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, Frame* parent) 
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size), 
        bleConnector(std::make_unique<BluetoothConnector>()),
        mainPanel(new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0,0), wxSize(size.x, size.y / 4 * 3), wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, "Main Panel")),
        sizer (new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL))

{
bledevListView = std::make_unique<wxListView>(new wxListView(mainPanel, ID_Bluetooth,
     wxPoint(size.GetWidth() - size.GetWidth() + 20, size.GetHeight() - size.GetHeight() + 20),
     wxSize(size.GetWidth() - 50, size.GetHeight() / 2)));

    bledevListView->AppendColumn("Address");
    bledevListView->SetColumnWidth(0, getBLEListViewSize().x/ 2);
    bledevListView->AppendColumn("Name");
    bledevListView->SetColumnWidth(1, getBLEListViewSize().x / 2); 

    stopDiscButton = new wxButton(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Stop discovery", wxPoint(0,0), STOPDISCSIZE,         wxBU_LEFT, wxDefaultValidator, "Stop disc");

    sizer->Add(bledevListView.get(), 1 ,wxEXPAND, 1);
    sizer->Add(stopDiscButton );
    mainPanel->SetSizer(sizer);
}
```

wxSizeEvent function

```
void BluetoothConnectFrame::OnSize(wxSizeEvent & e) {
   size = e.GetSize();
   mainPanel->SetSize(getMainPanelSize());
   sizer->Layout();
}
```

Printing out bledevListView size in OnSize event would print the correct values. However the UI does not update the ListView to match these values. I have tried using SetSize(), Update(), Refresh() on bledevListView and also tried resizing wxListView without using wxSizer but nothing would work. Any tips?

Comment: The idea of using sizers is to not handle sizing yourself. But this is what you are attempting in `OnSize()`. You are also showing too little code, so here are some Questions and Problems that you already have:
Q: How do you connect the event handler? P: You are setting the entire size to a child, while it can only occupy the _client size_ at most. Q: What happens when you remove the handler entirely? Hint: if `mainPanel` is the only child of `BluetoothConnectFrame`, then it should be sized automatically; if the frame has other children too, add them all to another sizer, set to the frame.

Comment: @catalin I used event table to for the OnSize and removing the that compeletly had the exact effect you proposed it would, it sized it automatically. However it still did nothing to my ListView so I decided to make second ListView to see if the problem is somewhere there (this time raw pointer) and with that it finally resized it. Although it did not resize the columns but instead added a third column that was then only resized. Thanks for the comment, it helped me figure out at least part of the problem. Although still wonder why my list above didn't work..

Comment: @Mizkei, is there any reason you want the smart pointer on the wxWidgets GUI class?

Comment: As catalin also commented, why are you trying to resize an item yourself? If you need to take an action during resize, take the action on the parent window (wxTopLevelWindow, such as wxFrame etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted in comments, you can do layout yourself explicitly in `wxEVT_SIZE` handler or (and this is the exclusive or) use sizers. To do the latter, start by removing your `OnSize()` handler for the frame entirely. What you may still want to have is an `wxEVT_SIZE` handler for the list view itself, which could resize its columns as you want.

Second problem in the code you show is even worse: you give ownership of `wxListView` to a `unique_ptr<>`. Unless you call `release()` on it at some later time, this is very wrong: all GUI elements are owned by wxWidgets and will be deleted by it. You need to use raw pointers or, if you prefer, non-owning smart pointer type (`observer_ptr<>`) for all `wxWindow`-derived objects in your program (but this also applies to sizers and, basically, anything that you "give" to the framework to be managed by it).